# Strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS with [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated]

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my app, I switch between views modally. My problem is, when I move from the first viewController to the second, it works. When I dismiss the second view for the first time, that also works. Where is the problem, you say? It's coming. When I move from the first viewController to the second a second time, it works again. Just as it should. Yet when I try to dismiss the second viewController the SECOND time, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

line.

Why does it crash the second time, but never the first time?

EDIT ONE:

This error happens no matter which viewController I switch to:

If I move from A to B, then back to A, then to B, then try to go back to A: crash
If I move from A to C, then back to A, then to C, then try to go back to A: crash again

EDIT TWO:

I create/show the view controller with this code:

```
MapView *controller = [[MapView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Should I be releasing this object after its creation?

Problem solved. Offending line of code was being used earlier for the transition I was using before I used modal views, and I forgot to remove it. Win.

Comment: Search for enabling NSZombies with XCode4

Comment: Already did that, provided little to no information

Comment: The console gives me no information or error report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error means you are trying to reference a deallocated object, i.e. you are over-releasing something. Check back through your memory management, maybe run the Build/Build and Analyze tool.

And yes, you should call `[controller release];` after presenting the viewcontroller modally.

Comment: But what could be over-released? Self? How would that even happen?

Comment: With NSLog, I confirmed that self is not null when dismiss is called; what else could be causing the problem?